# DateTime calculation including DST and UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, utc, dst

I have a (maybe) simple problem calculating the correct DST DateTime in Sql Server 2008 query. Let me explain:

We have a table, lets say T_User, with some columns regarding user data which can be modified by the user itself. Among other things, we also have two DateTime columns, sysDatetTimeCreated and sysDateTimeModified. To update these values we use the GetUtcDate() function and that works perfect. Every user has also a column with a TimeZoneValue. So if the user is in Eastern Europe and has a TimeZone value (UTC+1:00), and modifies his user properties in the table, the sysDateTimeModified column will be updated with the GetUtcDate() value.

On a web form, i want to show the user the real datetime, according to his TimeZone which is set in the Table.
The problem here is the the DST is not included. Here is my Example:

```
sysDateTimeCreated(UTC)       sysDateTimeModified(UTC)           CalculatedDateTimeModified(wrong)         FinalDateTimeModification(should be)

2016-04-06 08:08:27.657       2016-04-06 08:18:17.227            2016-04-06 09:18:17.227                   2016-04-06 10:18:17.227
```

Another thing, if the user moves from Europe to North America, The user TimeZone will change to (UTC-05:00). When the user data is updated, system will store the correct utc date, but the user will see the correct date according to his current timezone: DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()).

How to include DST to be used when its needed? -Example: North America (or any other country) does not use the DST and Europe does...

These calculation must be done in SQL, not code behind somewhere...

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't determine DST based on time zone. You need a table with DST start and end dates for each location. (and you do know time zones are not always full hours?)

Comment: I know that about full hours...